# How to remove 'contenteditable' attribute when saving html in JQuery

Tags: jquery

$mydiv's child elements are editable. I want to save html into db and expect small html. The following property removal not work.

How to make it work?

```
let big_html = $mydiv.html();

$mydiv.children().each(function () {
  $(this).removeProp('contenteditable');   // Not work!
});

let small_html = $mydiv.html();
```

Comment: Still not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

contenteditable is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) not a property

you can manipulate it

```
$(this).attr('contenteditable',true) // or false
```

or remove it:

```
$(this).removeAttr('contenteditable')
```

Comment: I see. It seems can't be removed. I have to make false when saving.

Comment: well you can use `removeAttr()`